# Unable to save resource prestashop webservice

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5, prestashop-1.7

I am new to prestashop web service ,when I add new customer it says one error .

```
RETURN HTTP BODY
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<errors>
<error>
<code><![CDATA[46]]></code>
<message><![CDATA[Unable to save resource]]></message>
</error>
</errors>
</prestashop>
```

can you guys help me how to solve this error..

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far. And what's the version of Prestashop you are trying to save to.

Answer (score 1):

Error similar to this are documented before. Activate DEBUG MODE and you will be able to see detailed error.

Good luck.